# WatchOS sendMessage received by iPhone inconsistent and delayed

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, watchos-2

This is the first time developing something with the WatchOS. I am trying to trigger an action using the WCSession sendMessage sending a value and trigger that action. Now it does work, but it's very inconsistent and delayed. Initially when the app opens sendMessage is triggered with a button on the Apple Watch app, but it doesn't do anything on the iPhone for 10 - 20 seconds. After that each time the buttons is pressed it triggers the action on the iPhone, but sometime it takes a second or two, other times it takes 5 - 10 seconds.

This is sending the message to the iPhone:

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] sendMessage:message
                           replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {
                               //handle reply from iPhone app here
                           }
                           errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                               //catch any errors here
                           }
 ];
```

This is where it's being recieved:

```
- (void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveMessage:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)message replyHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * __nonnull))replyHandler {

    NSString* command = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [message objectForKey:@"message"]];

    //Use this to update the UI instantaneously (otherwise, takes a little while)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.label setText:command];
        [SampleCameraApi actTakePicture:self];
        [self progressIndicator:YES];
    });

}
```

It's very basic as of right now, but I just want to figure out why it's so inconsistent or if there is a better way to go about it. Sending the message isn't really as important as triggering the action on the iPhone.